# how to append items to the same row or line with ng-repeat (How to use ng- repeat in angular js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

`In my result row It only brings the same value for different clients,  But it has to be a different value.What should I do for each result to be different?

I want the code to search the visit type and return visittype
`var searchpro = visitService.search(searchParams).then(function (response) { var results = response.data.results; $scope.existedActiveVisits = results; var b= response.data.results[0].visitType.name;`
`

This brings the result for visittype
`{{existedActiveVisits[0].visitType.name}}` -this is the call for the function

After calling this function , it will bring the same value for the column
`